# Solutions cannot cross

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I understand for for the initial value problem:

$\frac{dx}{dt}=f(x) \quad$  $x_0=x(0)$

If I have two solutions $x_1(t),x_2(t)$ defined on the same interval with the same initial condition satisfying the above initial value problem then $x_1(t)=x_2(t)$.
However, why if I have two solutions, with **different** initial conditions are they unable to cross one another? i.e $x_1(t)\neq x_2(t)$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If they do cross at $t=t^*$, then both are solutions to some initial value problem with the same initial value at $t^*$.

This all supposes that the ODE satisfies at least the local  Lipschitz condition.