Picard-Lindelöf theorem uniqueness inside rectangle
I am trying to understand the Picard-Lindelöf theorem from Wikipedia. Am I correct in drawing the conclusion that two solutions $y_1(t),y_2(t)$ of the general equation $y'(t)=f(t,y(t))$ will intersect each other in $D$ if and only if they are equal inside $D$? Intuitively this makes sense to me since if $y_1,y_2$ would be equal somewhere but diverge from each other somewhere in $D$, there must be a point inside $D$ from which they diverge (since $y_1,y_2$ are continuous), and this point would then not be intersected by only one solution in any neighbourhood of it. I am not entirely convinced by my reasoning though, so I would love for someone to verify or disprove it!

Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1237327/42969
